# Can't compile Angular2 TS code after RxJS update

Tags: angular, rxjs

Since I've updated my RxJS to the latest version (5.4.3 and can't downgrade), I'm having this error:

> Error:(94, 9) TS2322:Type 'Promise' is not
>   assignable to type 'Promise'.   Types of property 'then' are
>   incompatible.
>       Type '(onfulfilled?: (value: number | ErrorObser...' is not assignable
>   to type '{ (onFulfilled?: (value: number) => U | Thenable,
>   onRejected?: (error: any) => U | Thenable...'.
>         Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onFulfilled' are incompatible.
>           Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
>             Type 'number | ErrorObservable' is not assignable to type 'number'.
>               Type 'ErrorObservable' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Here's my code:

```
countFiles(from:any = false, limit:any = false, search: any = null, parent_page_id: any = ''): Promise<number> {
         (...) // Some code

        return this.http
            .post(this.apiUrl + 'v1/countFiles', JSON.stringify(params), {headers: headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => <number> response.json()['count'])
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

Error handler function:

```
private handleError(error: any) {
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';


        if(typeof error._body !== 'undefined') {
            let body = <HTMLElement> document.querySelector('body');
            body.innerHTML = '';
            document.write(error._body);
        }

        this.alertService.addAlert('error','error.general');

        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
```

Anybody can help?

Comment: I second Kld, 2.4.2 to be exact

Comment: You should include the code for `handleError`, too.

Comment: @dockleryxk - I don't understand you. I've done a mistake in a RxJS version. It was 5.4.3, not 5.4.2, but I don't know what you had in mind when writing your comment.

Comment: @cartant - I've added it in the post. Thanks!

Comment: Kld deleted their comment, so that made me look like an idiot! Their comment had said to check that your typescript is version 2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `countFiles` is defined as returning `Promise<number>`:

```ts
countFiles(
  from: any = false,
  limit: any = false,
  search: any = null,
  parent_page_id: any = ''
): Promise<number> {
  // ...
  return this.http
    .post(this.apiUrl + 'v1/countFiles', JSON.stringify(params), { headers: headers })
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => <number>response.json()['count'])
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

It uses `toPromise` to convert the observable to a promise. (I'll assume you have a good reason for doing so, as converting an observable to a promise is considered to be an antipattern.) So the `catch` to which `handleError` is passed is part of the promise chain - not the observable chain.

However, `handleError` returns an observable:

```ts
private handleError(error: any) {
  // ...
  return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

Instead of returning an observable, just throw the error.

You have another problem, too. Within `handleError`, you use `this`. However, it will not be bound to what you think it is, as you pass it to `catch` like this:

```ts
catch(this.handleError)
```

You could solve that problem with an arrow function:

```ts
catch(error => this.handleError(error))
```

Regarding your fix, it 'works' because `Promise<ErrorObservable>` is compatible with `Promise<any>`, so TypeScript does not complain. But it won't work the way you are expecting - no error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. For some reason, it requires to change  to  in the return "then" function. Below I'm posting the working code.

```
countFiles(from:any = false, limit:any = false, search: any = null, parent_page_id: any = ''): Promise<number> {
         (...) // Some code

        return this.http
            .post(this.apiUrl + 'v1/countFiles', JSON.stringify(params), {headers: headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => <any> response.json()['count'])
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

Nothing else has been changed.